# Why is a conditional channel source causing a downstream process to not execute an instance for each value in a different channel?

Tags: nextflow

I have a Nextflow DSL2 pipeline where an early process generally takes a very long time (~24 hours) and has intermediate products that occupy a lot of storage (~1 TB). Because of the length and resources required for this process, it would be desirable to be able to set a "checkpoint", i.e. save the (relatively small) final output to a safe location, and on subsequent pipeline executions retrieve the output from that location. This means that the intermediate data can be safely deleted without preventing resumption of the pipeline later.

However, I've found that when I implement this and use the checkpoint, a process further downstream that is supposed to run an instance for every value in a list only runs a single instance. Minimal working example and example outputs below:

```
// foobarbaz.nf
nextflow.enable.dsl=2

params.publish_dir = "$baseDir/output"
params.nofoo = false

xy = ['x', 'y']
xy_chan = Channel.fromList(xy)

process foo {
    publishDir "${params.publish_dir}/", mode: "copy"

    output:
        path "foo.out"
    
    """
    touch foo.out
    """
}

process bar {
    input:
        path foo_out

    output:
        path "bar.out"

    script:
        """
        touch bar.out
        """    
}

process baz {
    input:
        path bar_out
        val xy

    output:
        tuple val(xy), path("baz_${xy}.out")

    script:
        """
        touch baz_${xy}.out
        """
}

workflow {
    main:
        if( params.nofoo ) {
            foo_out = Channel.fromPath("${params.publish_dir}/foo.out")
        }
        else {
            foo_out = foo() // generally takes a long time and uses lots of storage
        }

        bar_out = bar(foo_out)
        baz_out = baz(bar_out, xy_chan)

        // ... continue to do things with baz_out ...
}
```

First execution with `foo`:

```
$ nextflow foobarbaz.nf 
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 21.10.6
Launching `foobarbaz.nf` [soggy_gautier] - revision: f4e70a5cd2
executor >  local (4)
[77/c65a9a] process > foo     [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
[23/846929] process > bar     [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
[18/1c4bb1] process > baz (2) [100%] 2 of 2 ✔
```

(note that `baz` successfully executes two instances: one where `xy==x` and one where `xy==y`)

Later execution using the checkpoint:

```
$ nextflow foobarbaz.nf --nofoo
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 21.10.6
Launching `foobarbaz.nf` [infallible_babbage] - revision: f4e70a5cd2
executor >  local (2)
[40/b42ed3] process > bar (1) [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
[d9/76888e] process > baz (1) [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
```

The checkpointing is successful (`bar` executes without needing `foo`), but now `baz` only executes a single instance where `xy==x`.

Why is this happening, and how can I get the intended behaviour? I see no reason why whether `foo_out` comes from `foo` or retrieved directly from a file should make any difference to how the `xy` channel is interpreted by `baz`.

Comment: If this process takes a long time to run and produces quite sizeable intermediate files that aren't needed downstream, why not just `rm` them immediately after the long running command completes successfully (i.e. exit status zero)? Not sure exactly what's needed here, but the [storeDir](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#storedir) directive _could_ be useful if you need a permanent cache of your process results.

Comment: Really, this "process" is actually a DSL2 workflow, so it has its own subprocesses and therefore would be really desirable to be able to resume it in certain cases. It's also something that is run five times in parallel with different data and different processing parameters, and each of the five finishes at rather different times. My intention is to only use `--nofoo` when all five have been completed, but not before. In short this seemed like the best solution to my specific situation with my complex pipeline, but I agree that in the simplest case, just `rm` the files when you know it's safe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the [Channel.fromPath](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#frompath) factory method creates a [queue channel](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#queue-channel) to provide a single value, whereas the output of process 'foo' implicitly produces a [value channel](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#value-channel):

> A value channel is implicitly created by a process when an input
> specifies a simple value in the `from` clause. Moreover, a value channel
> is also implicitly created as output for a process whose inputs are
> only value channels.

So without `--nofoo`, 'foo_out' and 'bar_out' are both value channels. Since, 'xy_chan' is a queue channel that provides two values, process 'bar' gets executed twice. With `--nofoo`, 'foo_out' and 'bar_out' are both queue channels which provide a single value. Since there's only one complete input configuration (i.e. one value from each input channel), process 'bar' gets executed only once. See also: [Understand how multiple input channels work](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#understand-how-multiple-input-channels-work).

The solution is to ensure that 'foo_out' is either, always a queue channel or always value channel. Given your 'foo' process declaration, you probably want the latter:

```
if( params.nofoo ) {
    foo_out = file( "${params.publish_dir}/foo.out" )
}
else {
    foo_out = foo()
}
```

Comment: Accepting this for explaining and giving a simpler, nicer solution!

Answer (score -1):

In my experience a process is executed according to the input channel with lowest N of emissions (which is one path emission from bar in your case).
So in this case the strange behaviour is actually the example without `--nofoo` in my mind.
If you want it executed 2 time you may try to combine the Channels using combine something like `baz_input_ch=bar.out.combine(xy_chan)`

Comment: Using this channel combination gives me the intended behaviour, so marking as the best answer. Still don't know *why* this happens though!

Comment: -1 There's really no need to combine your input channels like this. Much better to ensure that 'foo_out' is always either a queue channel or a value channel.